# Swift Webkit Load After Page Loads

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I am trying to call a javascript file AFTER the page has completely loaded.

Heres what I have:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let fileLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("javascriptfile", ofType: "js")!
    let jsContent : String
    do {
        jsContent = try String(contentsOfFile: fileLocation, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
    catch {
        jsContent = ""
    }

    myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsContent)

    print("Webview did finish load")
}
```

But I learned that it is not calling after the page gets loaded. Its more so after the webview has loaded in general. Is this right? How do I call after the page actually loads..

I believe this because I simply added `alert("Hello World!");` to the javascript file and the alert will show then the web page loads.